# C++ ofstream output not indenting correctly

Tags: c++, file-io, ofstream

I am outputting names and grades to a file and it needs to be in a specific format.

I currently have this code to write to the file

```
void outToFile(Student a[], ofstream& b, int c){
  b << "Student Grade Summary\n";
  b << "---------------------\n\n";
  b << "ENGLISH CLASS\n\n";
  b << "Student Name\t\t" << "Test Avg\n";
  b << "------------------------------------------------\n";
  for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i){
    if(a[i].course == "E"){
        b << a[i].first << " " << a[i].last << "\t\t" << a[i].avg << "\t";
        if(a[i].avg >= 90)
            b << "A\n";
        else if(a[i].avg >= 80)
            b << "B\n";
        else if(a[i].avg >= 70)
            b << "C\n";
        else if(a[i].avg >= 60)
            b << "D\n";
        else if (a[i].avg < 60)
            b << "F\n";
        else
            b << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

which writes this to the txt file

```
Student Grade Summary
---------------------

ENGLISH CLASS

Student Name        Test Avg
------------------------------------------------
Marvin Dipwart      86.5    B
Axelrod Polinski        61.9    D
James T. Kirk       79.6    C
```

as you can see the indenting is wrong and i need it to all line up.
how would i fix this?

Comment: That's because the second name is longer. Simply adding a fixed amount of tabs won't make it line up. You should really use a different output format, e.g. CSV, or make the columns fixed-width with spaces for padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to concatenate the first and last names, and specify a width for the combination, something like this:

```
b << std::setw(30) << (a[i].first + " " + a[i].last) << "\t" << a[i].avg;
```